# ggplot sum and mean?

Tags: r

How would I be able to do a line showing the median of the sum?

What I currently have

```
dataset$`Created Date`<- gsub("T.*","",dataset$`Created Date`)
dataset$`Created Date`<- ymd(strptime(dataset$`Created Date`, format="%Y-%m-%d"))

names(dataset) <- gsub(" ","_",names(dataset)) #rename column to remove space
dfcount <- data.frame(count(dataset, `Created_Date`)) #create dataframe

dfcount$Created_Date <- as.POSIXlt(dfcount$Created_Date) #Convert to POSIX for weekdayfilter
Monthlywithavg <- ggplot(dfcount,aes(Month, n))+
 stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "line") + 
 scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m"))+
 stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line")

Monthlywithavg
```

Let me know if there's anything else I should change too.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a small sample of your data for us to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another alternative to CPak's, it is essentially the same.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

agg = plyr::ddply(mtcars,'cyl',summarize,mpg = sum(mpg) )
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="line") +
  geom_hline(data = agg,aes(yintercept = median(mpg)),color="red")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone has a better answer but I think you'll have to calculate the median of the sum yourself. See this reproducible example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

median_of_sum <- mtcars %>%
            group_by(cyl) %>%
            summarise(sum = sum(mpg)) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            summarise(median = median(sum))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="line") + 
  geom_hline(data=median_of_sum, aes(yintercept=median), color="red")
```

Comment: Hey, I tried doing that but getting an error sum not defined for "Date" objects